# Background Colour of JCheckBox

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

Is there any way to change the background colour of a `JCheckBox` ? I mean the colour inside the little square, not everything around it which is what `setBackground` does.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to implement your own `Icon`.